# rails get output from controller methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, controller

I have the following code in my Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def get_mkts(all_idx)
    mkts = Set.new
    all_idx.each do |idx|
      m = decode_index_names(idx) 
      puts m[:mkt]
      mkts.add(m[:mkt])
    end
  end


  def decode_index_names(name)
      mkt = name.split(/[0-9]/)[0]
      type = get_first_num(mkt);
      {:mkt => mkt,:type => type}
  end

  def get_first_num(str)
    str[/\d+/]
  end
end
```

And I'm inputting an array of strings like this:

```
 ["USEQUITIES2tv10", "USEQUITIES2tv15", "USEQUITIES2tv20", "NONUSEQUITIES2tv5", "NONUSEQUITIES2tv10", "NONUSEQUITIES2tv15", "NONUSEQUITIES2tv20", "BONDS2tv5", "BONDS2tv10", "BONDS2tv15", "BONDS2tv20"
, "ES1", "ES2tv5", "ES2tv10", "ES2tv15", "ES2tv20", "NQ1", "NQ2tv5", "NQ2tv10", "NQ2tv15", "USBONDS2tv5", "USBONDS2tv10", "USBONDS2tv15", "USBONDS2tv20", "GERMANBONDS2tv5", "GERMANBONDS2tv10", "GERMANB
ONDS2tv15", "GERMANBONDS2tv20", "EQUITIESnBONDS2tv5", "EQUITIESnBONDS2tv10", "EQUITIESnBONDS2tv15", "EQUITIESnBONDS2tv20", "COMMODITIES2tv5", "COMMODITIES2tv10", "COMMODITIES2tv15", "COMMODITIES2tv20",
 "CURRENCIES2tv5"]
```

The method get_mkts is supposed to loop through, extract the text up tot the first number and create a unique array of symbols (which is why i used Set). However, I can't get the method to output anything other than the original input. In rails console I'm able to see from the output of "puts m[:mkt]" that each loop through is getting the correct value, I just don't know how to return the set mkts instead of the input value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby methods return the result of the last statement if you don't use `return`. In your case it's `each` and that's why you get the input back. You can do something like this:

```
def get_mkts(all_idx)
  mkts = Set.new
  all_idx.each do |idx|
    m = decode_index_names(idx) 
    puts m[:mkt]
    mkts.add(m[:mkt])
  end
  mkts
end
```

This will return the `mkts` set instead of `all_idx`.

Comment: ah ok that was so simple.. what a waste of an hour lol thanks

Answer (score 0):

The method can be rewritten has:

```
def get_mkts(all_idx)
  all_idx.map { |idx| decode_index_names(idx) }.uniq
end
```

Looks more rubyish and its shorter and cleaner

Comment: This doesn't actually quite work because the output of decode_index_names is a two item hash and i want the output to just be a grouping of the first items of that hash